# If $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{A_k}$ and $Y_n=X_n/{EX_n}$, then $P(A_n\text{ i.o.}) \ge P(\lim\sup Y_n>0)$

Tags: probability

$A_n$ is a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$.

Why the result $P(A_n\text{ i.o.}) \ge P(\lim\sup Y_n>0)$ implied by the definition of $Y_n$?

**Edit.** If I add a condition $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_{k}\right)=\infty$, will this statement be true?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $P(A_n i.o. )$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true.

Let $A_{1}=\Omega$ and $A_{k}=\varnothing$ for $k\geq2$.

Then $X_{n}=1=Y_{n}$ for each $n$ hence $P\left(\limsup Y_{n}>0\right)=1$.

However $P\left(A_{n}\text{ i.o.}\right)=0$.

---

**edit**

Concerning the case under the extra condition $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_{k}\right)=\infty$.

If $\omega\notin\limsup A_{n}$ then $m,N\in\mathbb{N}$ exists
with $n\geq N\implies X_{n}\left(\omega\right)=m\wedge\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)>0$ and
consequently $Y_{n}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{m}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}P\left(A_{k}\right)}$.

Then condition $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_{k}\right)=\infty$
tells us that $\limsup Y_{n}\left(\omega\right)=0$.

Proved is now that $$\left(\limsup A_{n}\right)^{c}\subseteq\left\{ \limsup Y_{n}=0\right\}$$
or equivalently $$\left\{ \limsup Y_{n}=0\right\} ^{c}\subseteq\limsup A_{n}$$

Since the $Y_{n}\left(\omega\right)$ cannot take negative values
this means exactly that: $$\left\{ \limsup Y_{n}>0\right\} \subseteq\limsup A_{n}$$

Conclusion:

$$P\left(\limsup A_{n}\right)\geq P\left(\limsup Y_{n}>0\right)$$

Comment: i see, but if i add a condition that $\sum P(A_k)=\infty$ ,will this statement be true?

Comment: I think so. See my edit.